# Angular 2 Material Table - DataSource not triggered

Tags: angular, datasource, angular-material2

I'm following the official documentation for implementing a table with sorting and pagination, here my code:

```
export class AccountsTableComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource: AccountsDataSource | null;
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'roles', 'registration_date', 'enabled'];

  @ViewChild(MdPaginator) paginator: MdPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MdSort) sort: MdSort;

  constructor(public _accountApiService: AccountApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new AccountsDataSource(this._accountApiService, this.paginator, this.sort);
  }
}

export class AccountsDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  totalElements = 0;

  constructor(private _accountsApi: AccountApiService,
              private _paginator: MdPaginator,
              private _sort: MdSort) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<User[]> {

    const displayDataChanges = [
      this._sort.mdSortChange,
      this._paginator.page,
    ];

    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).mergeMap(() => this.getData());
  }

  disconnect() {}

  getData(): Observable<User[]> {
    const order = (this._sort.direction !== '' && this._sort.direction === 'desc') ? '-' : '+';
    const sort = (this._sort.active) ? order + this._sort.active : null;

    return this._accountsApi.getAll({
      sort: sort,
      page: this._paginator.pageIndex,
      size: this._paginator.pageSize
    }).map(res => {
      if (res.content && res.content.length > 0) {
        this.totalElements = (res.totalElements) ? res.totalElements : 0;

        return res.content;
      }
      return [];
    });
  }
}
```

And here the component.

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" mdSort>

    <!-- ID Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="accountId">
      <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> ID </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Username Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="accountUsername">
      <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Username </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.username}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Email Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="accountEmail">
      <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Email </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.email}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
    <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>
  </md-table>

  <md-paginator #paginator
                [length]="dataSource.totalElements"
                [pageIndex]="0"
                [pageSize]="25"
                [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
  </md-paginator>
</div>
```

When the component is displayed i'm receiving this error in console:

> ERROR Error: cdk-table: Could not find column with id "id".

I've tried with a console.log() inside the connect() method and it seems it is never invoked. Any idea why?

About the `const displayDataChanges`, I've took from the demo code, but I'm not really sure what does that mean and if it is helpful in my case, can anybody explain what is it?

### Update

I've applied the following changes.

```
export class AccountsTableComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new AccountsDataSource(this._accountApiService, this.paginator, this.sort);
    this.dataSource.refresh();
  }
  ...
}


export class AccountsDataSource extends DataSource<User> {
  private dataChange: BehaviorSubject<User[]> = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>([]);

  ...

  connect(): Observable<User[]> {
    const displayDataChanges = [
      this.dataChange,
      this._sort.mdSortChange,
      this._paginator.page,
    ];

    return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).mergeMap(() => this.getData());
  }

  refresh(): void {
    this.dataChange.next([]);
  }
}
```

With the method refresh() i can trigger the data refresh from the server.

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to create the table but it fails. The error comes from `cdkColumnDef`, it has to match the column name defined in `displayedColumns`.

Answer (score 0):

in your cdkColumnDef 'id' column is defined as "accountId" where as in the displayedColumn array it is just 'id'.they should match in order to create the table. I think that might be the issue.

```
  <!-- ID Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="accountId">                //here
      <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> ID </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

change ' accountId ' to ' id '. It will probably resolve the issue..